# How to search for a certain text or "string" in html using javascript? (chrome extensiont)

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a chrome extension whereby when it detects a certain string, it will display a certain html page on the extension. So I tried to use .search followed by an "if else statement". To make it clear that it is working, I've set an alert within the "if else". But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help?
Here's the javascript file

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
    var node = element.childNodes[j];

    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue;
        var searchText = text.search(/nmd/g);
        // var replacedText = text.replace(/nmd/gi, 'nmdReplaced');
        if(searchText == text){
            alert("connected");
        }

        if (replacedText !== text) {
            element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The text.replace works, but that's not what I'm trying to get it to do.

Answer (score 0):

[`Search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Return_value) Methods returns the `index` of matched string or pattern not the string itself, If not matches anything then it returns `-1`

so your  `if(searchText == text)` will always fail and it goes to else part, You can simply check for `if(searchText !== -1)`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I actually went ahead and did it, but met with a new problem. The alert did come out, but it kept looping and the page kept refreshing. So I ended up with a broken link/usable link/a site that kept refreshing forever. How do I make the alert come out only once? Edit: not only that, the alert also comes out on every site without the characters "nmd".

Comment: @Benjamin can you create a [`Minimum running example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will look into it

Comment: I'm very sorry, am very new to this. What exactly is a Minimum runnign example? Do I post my codes into JSFiddle or something?

Comment: @Benjamin you can read the link added on above comment, yes something like that only anything JSfiddle or JSbin or anything.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I meant that I'm not very sure what the link is talking about. I'm extremely guilty for troubling you. Edit: I dont exactly know how to create a minimal running example, or fit the javascript code into jsfiddle since this is a chrome extension which will run instantly. My file only contains a manifest.JSON file and a javascript file, that's about it